# How to set a max-width only to text nodes not in a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have mixed well and bad formatted text from a legacy wordpress database. Well formated is inside `p` tags and bad formatted is outside. So at the end the HTML is like that:

```
<div>
    <p>Good text</p>
    <blockquote>Good text</blockquote>
    Problematic text <strong>like this</strong> one.
    <p>Good text</p>
</div>
```

The `p` text has a max-width set and is centered:

```
p {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The `blockquote` element or other `div`s are not width-limited.

As you can see in [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rr4273u2/2/), my problem is that the `non-p` text is left-aligned. I don't know if it's possible to center using just CSS. Using javascript my approach was to do this:

```
jQuery("div").contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; }).wrap('<p>');
```

This is ok in general, buy when you have `strong` or `em` tags in the middle it doesn't work ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/4tp4r03x/)).

So, is CSS able to do this? If not, how to do in Javascript? Of course, I prefer the CSS option, but JS is a better option than reformat the whole database :)

**Clarification**: The objective is to limit with max-width only the p-tags and the bad-fomatted text elements (which include text and some tags like `strong` or `em`). Other elements must have 100% width, it is, not limited by the 300px max-width (i.e. blockquote must use all the available screen size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jQuery solution that will wrap the contents that aren't already in `<p>` or `<blockquote>`.

Can be easily adapted to include other acceptable tags

```
var $container = $('div'),
    $contents = $container.contents();

var validTags = ['P', 'BLOCKQUOTE'];
var newP = null;
$contents.each(function (i) {
    if (this.nodeType === 3 || $.inArray(this.tagName, validTags) == -1) {
        if (!newP) { // start creating a new <p>
            newP = $('<p style="color:red">')
        }
        newP.append(this); // append to the new <p>
    } else {
        if (newP) {
            $(this).before(newP); //insert new <p> if there is one
            newP = null; //reset
        }
    }
    /* in case text is after all valid tags, add to end */
    if (i == $contents.length - 1 && newP) {
        $container.append(newP);
    }
});
```

Note that `<div>` can't be appended to `<p>` (invalid child) so this approach would probably need some more refinement for situations like that. It does work on sample provided however

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oo15ej32/3)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the pure CSS solution, but it's interesting to have also a JQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

To center all the content inside the div:

CSS:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

To center some divs (example 1st and 3rd from 4), selecting them by id:

CSS:

```
div#sect1, div#sect3{
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sect1>
    <!-- contents -->
</div>
<div id="sect2>
    <!-- contents -->
</div>
<div id="sect3>
    <!-- contents -->
</div>
<div id="sect4>
    <!-- contents -->
</div>
```

Comment: As you can see, this is not a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rr4273u2/2/ It still overfits the max-width limit when the text is not inside the p-tag

Comment: div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 700px;
}

Comment: div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 300px;
}

Comment: This sets a max-width also for blockquote. Blockquote-tag must have 100% width (the whole page)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same styles to the body and the strong tags:

```
strong {
font-weight: normal; margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;}
body {

max-width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body{
    text-align:center;
}
div:before{
    text-align:center;
    max-width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

p{
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

blockquote{
    font-size: 2em;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's very near. Only that you have set the blockquote to 700px and must be 100%. But this is ok. Thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry, isn't valid, I haven't tested until now and the text outside the p is still not limited to 300px: http://jsfiddle.net/3zhq87py/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply the max-width on the container element and remove it from other descendent elements.

```
div.container {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tp4r03x/1/).

EDIT:
you can use the negative margins if you know your main container width. e.g. use -150px margin if your content area is 300px and it's container is 600px and you want bloquote to be 600px wide.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tp4r03x/2/)

Comment: Because the effect I'm looking for is that some elements like blockquote tag have 100% width. In your example, the blockquote is also limited to 300px

Comment: Well, in this case the blockquote don't use all the space available, is fixed to a 300px +- 150px. It won't be a bad solution anyway, but @wishab gave the answer I was looking for.